# Problema firma SoapHeader mediante proxy visual studio

Tags: c#

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un wsdl referenciado con visual studio 2017, en cual genera automaticamente un proxy para poder consumir el servicio. Para que pueda utilizar el servicio tengo que llevar un certificado de transport y tambien tiene que tener firmado con otro certificado la cabecera.

La arquitectura del proxy generado por visual studio se compone de muchas clases y atributos, en el cual un atributo del Bidding tiene un clase que hereda de SoapHeader.

El problema que tengo es que no puede añadir la firma a la cabecera con las herramientas que me autogenera el visual studio al referenciarlo como web service.

La fase 1 del proyecto ya la tengo hecha que era generar manualmanete el xml enviarla mediante soap ui  y que me dieran el visto bueno, pero en la fase 2 quiero que el usuario no utilice el soap ui y lo haga todo automatico.Para ello he creado un pequeño proyecto de consola que utiliza el proxy autogerenerdo relleno todo las clases y atributos que hacen falta pero cuando lo envio con su funcion me devuelven que la firma (cabecera) es erronea.

Ya no se que hacer
He probado cambiando el  `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol` por  `System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebService3` y con el contexto pero el web service me da excepcion de que la firma no tiene clave privada.

He intentado buscar para firmar o añadir una cabecera con el nodo firmado que ya genere en el xml de la fase 1 pero me sigue poniendo error de que no esta bien construido el xml.

Una duda que tengo si tengo ya formado el xml con toda las firmas y todos los datos ya para enviar (SoapUI) ¿se puede enviar a un wsdl de otra forma que no sea por proxy autogenerado por visual studio?.

Saludos

Comment: Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: En que desarrollaste tu servicio? asp.net, core o wcf? coloca el codigo que has realizado, tanto servicio como cliente